# Can VS be configured to automatically remove blank line(s) after text is cut?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, editor

Is there a way (or shortcut) to tell VS 2008 that it cuts a line like this:

**Before:**

```
Some Text here  
This gets cut  
Some Code there
```

**After:**

```
Some Text here

Some Code there
```

**What I want:**

```
Some Text here  
Some Code there
```

PS: I don't want to select the whole line or something like this... only the text I want to cut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you:
Just place cursor on the line you want to cut (no selection) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>. That cuts the line (leaving no blanks) and puts the text in the Clipboard. (tested in *MS VC# 2008 Express* with no additional settings I'm aware of)

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> also works.
Select a line and hit Shift-Delete it will remove the line and place that line in your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't select anything, just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> when the cursor is on the line.